# Google Website Translator - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: google-translate

I've got the Google Website translator widget on my site (www.ancient.eu.com). It used to work perfectly, but now I am not getting any translations. When I check the Chrome Console I see the following errors:

```
POST http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?anno=3&client=te&format=html&v=1.0&scid=e669185dd7423a09-043358cb90b67c5d-g813cc84edafdd3ce-12&logld=v10 502 (Bad Gateway 51001) element_main.js:248
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?anno=3&client=te&format=html&v=1.0&scid=e669185dd7423a09-043358cb90b67c5d-g813cc84edafdd3ce-12&logld=v10. Origin http://www.ancient.eu.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Does anyone know what went wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Jan

Comment: Your question should stress this error "Origin http://www.ancient.eu.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Now it is lost in horizontal scroll. Just my 2c